# Marginal independence v.s. joint independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Suppose that $X$ is independent with $Y$ and is also independent with $Z$. No further assumption is made about the joint distribution of $Y$ and $Z$. Does it follow that $X$ is independent with $(Y,Z)$?

I know the reverse direction is true and I suspect the direction is above is not true but I don't have a counterexample.

Comment: No.  Suppose you have a pool of people:  one woman with initials $A.C.$ , one woman with initials $B.D..$.  One man with initials $A.D.$ and another man with initials $B.C..$   You choose uniformly randomly from the group.  Let $X$ denote gender, $Y$ first initial, $Z$ last initial.

Comment: @lulu Can you turn that into an answer so that I can close the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As requested in the comments:

Although the desired claim sounds plausible, it isn't true.  To see a simple counterexample, suppose we look at four people:  Two women (with initials $A.C.$ and $B.D.$) and two men (with initials $A.D.$ and $B.C.$).  We imagine that we are drawing uniformly randomly from this pool.

Let $X$ be the event which determines gender, $Y$ the first initial, and $Z$ the second initial.  A quick calculation shows that $X,Y$ are independent as are $X,Z$.  Yet $Y,Z$ together determine $X$.