# $(X,Y)$ and $Z$ Gaussian with $Z \bot X$, $Z \bot Y$ implies $(X+Z,Y+Z)$ Gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus

Let $(X,Y)$ be a Gaussian vector and let $Z$ be a Gaussian random variable independent of $X$ and of $Y$. Is $(X+Z,Y+Z)$ a Gaussian vector?

Comment: There is a difference between Gaussian and jointly Gaussian.

Comment: @user98187609 Show that $(X,Y,Z)'$ is jointly normal using the fact that $(X,Y)$ and $Z$ are independent and each normal. Then the claim follows.

Comment: But I only know that $Z$ is independent of $X$ and $Z$ is independent of $Y$. I don't know that $Z$ is independent of $(X,Y)$.

Comment: Oh I see, should have read more carefully. This may be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1739885/178464